# 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'browserHistory'. from /src/App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm just getting started learning react in routing section but i'm kinda confusing about the error i got

## Failed to compile

> ./src/App.js
>
> 31:19-33 'react-router' does not contain an export named
> 'browserHistory'.

Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, hashHistory, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import logo from './assets/images/logo.svg';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={browserHistory} >
        <Route path="/" component={ Home }>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
const Home = () => <h1>Hello from Home!</h1>
const Address = () => <h1>We are located at 555 Jackson St.</h1>

export default App;
```

Comment: browserHistory was part of react-router v3.
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5263

Comment: Thank for the advice , do i must create route.jsx files ? or using app.js instead because i've see some tutorial using route.jsx as the route

Comment: in my opinion having a separated router file is much cleaner

Comment: Karim , can you give me an advice about how the correct way / best pratice for folder structure in react js ?

Comment: check this: https://gist.github.com/koistya/d7a507438c741ee6adb5

Answer (score 2):

You would need to upgrade to v4

You need to use `BrowserRouter` and `Switch` from 'react-router-dom` as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41701449/3125070), here's how you can use it:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom'
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <AppNavbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```